# Codeigniter load page from another server

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, cross-domain

Newbie and Need helps for Codeigniter and Javascript, i need load page from another server with CI too..
What should i do to make it works...

```
    $("#select").change(function(){
        if($('#textbox').val() == ""){
            alert("Warning");
            return;
        }else{
            $('#overlay').show();
            var tglpayslip = $('#tglpayslip').val();
            var url = "http://192.168.88.7/index.php/home/payslip.php";
            $.post(url, tglpayslip, function(response){
                $('#overlay').hide();
                $('#payslip').html(response);
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: You won't be able to do this in JavaScript due to same origin policy. You will need to use curl in PHP or develop an api for them to communicate.

Comment: thanks chris, i'll try it

Comment: [This](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.in/2013/09/jquery-cross-domain-ajax-request.html) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

For cross domain, you have to use JSONP.

```
$("#select").change(function(){
        if($('#textbox').val() == ""){
            alert("Warning");
            return;
        }else{
            $('#overlay').show();
            var tglpayslip = $('#tglpayslip').val();
            var url = "http://192.168.88.7/index.php/home/payslip.php";
            $.ajax({
               type:"post",
               url:url,
               dataType: "jsonp",
               data:tglpayslip,
               success:function(response){
               $('#overlay').hide();
                $('#payslip').html(response);
               }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
var tglpayslip = $('#tglpayslip').val();
var url = "http://192.168.88.7/index.php/home/payslip.php";
            $.ajax({
               crossDomain: true,
               type:"post",
               url:url,
               dataType: "jsonp",
               data:tglpayslip,
               success:function(response){
               $('#overlay').hide();
                $('#payslip').html(response);
               }
            });
```